# How can I learn about and keep track of major Magic tournaments in my local area?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, tournament

I've been interested in going to a large Magic tournament for a while now, though whether I *can* go and how far I could travel varies week by week.

I know how to look up the Grand Prix schedule and SGC tournaments. But I keep being surprised by other events — such as TCGPlayer tournaments, a different SGC formats, even PTQs, — only finding out about them when it's too late to make plans to go.

**How can I make sure I'm aware of big tournaments near me with more lead time?** Is there a resource that can show me tournament schedules from more than just one sponsor?

Answer (score 1):

The official M:tG site offers a [store and tournament locator](http://locator.wizards.com/). Just enter the name of the town you want to look up, and it will show you upcoming, official tournaments in that town and in an area around it.

Of course, this can only cover sanctioned tournaments that WotC knows about - for unofficial tournaments, your best bet is probably to get in touch with the local player base and store owners.

Comment: I went and messed with the filters a bit. I'm not clear on how you'd construct a search that finds GPs *and* the GP-like events hosted by SGC and TCGPlayer (which are sanctioned by the DCI) with that tool.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would have to look for them on the internet (most have Facebook pages). Also ask other people you know who play Magic.