# Want to find a website listing MTG groups in Japan

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want to find a group to play MTG with in Japan near my area that speaks English rather than Japanese, but I have been unsuccessful in finding a website that lists groups other than those located in a few main areas (Tokyo, Kyoto, etc.).

I would be very grateful if someone could provide me with information of a website or page where I can make contact with local players.

If this is not the correct place for this question, I would appreciate any tips on where the proper place would be.

Comment: You can find more useful information in [How can I learn about and keep track of major Magic tournaments in my local area?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/8213/6692) and [Getting started (Advanced) with Magic: The Gathering, and where to play](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/30075/6692).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use WOTC Store & Event locator at https://locator.wizards.com/.

With that you can find Events and Stores near you.

Comment: Just to elaborate, the Wizards website has its store locator. You can type any city/ town into the finder and it will show you places nearby. Otherwise Google is your friend :)